# Angular Typescript - exclude is not working in tsconfig.json

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, tsconfig

Currently I am facing issue with one of the modules inside node_modules while r compiling the Angular 4 Project and the getting the error as below hence I decided to exclude this project in the tsconfig.json but still I am getting the error, Can someone help me here

```
ERROR in D:/workspace/demo/node_modules/@types/d3-collection/index.d.ts (148,23): ',' expected.

ERROR in D:/workspace/demo/node_modules/@types/d3-collection/index.d.ts (483,40): ',' expected.

ERROR in D:/workspace/demo/node_modules/@types/d3-collection/index.d.ts (148,25): Type parameter name cannot be 'any'
```

Hence I decided to exclude the node_modules to avoid these errors but still I am facing the same error when running `npm start`

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: try this `"exclude": ["node_modules" ]`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez tried still same error

Answer (score 20):

you should add `skipLibCheck` it skips type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts).

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["d3-collection"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This helped to reduce 1 error but still other 2 errors persists

`ERROR in D:/workspace/demo/node_modules/@types/d3-collection/index.d.ts (148,23): ',' expected.

ERROR in D:/workspace/demo/node_modules/@types/d3-collection/index.d.ts (483,40): ',' expected.`

Comment: try this `"module": "es2015"`

Comment: try reinstalling the types `npm install @types/d3-collection --save-dev`