# Why is TypeScript not respecting "exclude" on my node_modules dir?

Tags: typescript

I am running into an issue with TypeScript where it is checking my `node_modules` directory. I am using yarn workspaces with a project structure setup as:

```
└─ .
   ├─ package.json
   ├─ packages
   │  ├─ admin
   │  │  ├─ src
   │  │  └─ tsconfig.json
   │  ├─ api
   │  │  ├─ package.json
   │  │  ├─ src
   │  │  ├─ tests
   │  │  ├─ tsconfig.json
   │  │  ├─ tsconfig.tsbuildinfo
   │  │  ├─ tslint.json
   │  ├─ client
   │  │  ├─ package.json
   │  │  ├─ tsconfig.json
   │  │  ├─ types.d.ts
   │  │  └─ updateDependencies.js
   │  └─ core
   │     ├─ package.json
   │     ├─ src
   │     ├─ tests
   │     └─ tsconfig.json
   ├─ tsconfig.json
   └─ yarn.lock
```

#### ./tsconfig.json

```
{
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "./node_modules/**/*", "node_modules", "dist"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@projectName/core": ["./packages/core/src"],
      "@projectName/api": ["./packages/api/src"],
      "@projectName/admin": ["./packages/admin/src"],
      "@projectName/client": ["./packages/client"]
    }
  }
}
```

*as an aside, `paths` doesn't work for me. I still have to traverse the tree, such as: `@projectName/core/src/models/whatever`*

#### ./packages/api/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2019",
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

#### Error Output

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ tsc
../../node_modules/@types/draft-js/index.d.ts:203:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Blob'.

203                 handlePastedFiles?(files: Array<Blob>): DraftHandleValue;
                                                    ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/draft-js/index.d.ts:206:77 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Blob'.

206                 handleDroppedFiles?(selection: SelectionState, files: Array<Blob>): DraftHandleValue;
                                                                                ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts:439:34 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

439         controls: Array<MVCArray<Node>>;
                                     ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts:1609:38 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

1609         setContent(content: string | Node): void;
                                          ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts:1622:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

1622         content?: string | Node;
                                ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts:2602:32 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

2602         constructor(container: Node, opts?: SaveWidgetOptions);
                                    ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts:2905:34 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

2905         controls: Array<MVCArray<Node>>;
                                      ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/isomorphic-fetch/index.d.ts:8:30 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'fetch'. Did you mean '_fetch'?

8 declare const _fetch: typeof fetch;
                               ~~~~~

  ../../node_modules/@types/isomorphic-fetch/index.d.ts:8:15
    8 declare const _fetch: typeof fetch;
                    ~~~~~~
    '_fetch' is declared here.

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/events.d.ts:86:59 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Window'.

86 export type FireFunction = (element: Document | Element | Window | Node, event: Event) => boolean;
                                                             ~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/events.d.ts:86:68 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

86 export type FireFunction = (element: Document | Element | Window | Node, event: Event) => boolean;
                                                                      ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/events.d.ts:88:54 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Window'.

88     [K in EventType]: (element: Document | Element | Window | Node, options?: {}) => boolean;
                                                        ~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/events.d.ts:88:63 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

88     [K in EventType]: (element: Document | Element | Window | Node, options?: {}) => boolean;
                                                                 ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/events.d.ts:91:54 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Window'.

91     [K in EventType]: (element: Document | Element | Window | Node, options?: {}) => Event;
                                                        ~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/events.d.ts:91:63 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.

91     [K in EventType]: (element: Document | Element | Window | Node, options?: {}) => Event;
                                                                 ~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/pretty-dom.d.ts:3:43 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

3 export function prettyDOM(dom?: Element | HTMLDocument, maxLength?: number, options?: OptionsReceived): string | false;
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/pretty-dom.d.ts:4:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

4 export function logDOM(dom?: Element | HTMLDocument, maxLength?: number, options?: OptionsReceived): void;
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/screen.d.ts:11:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

11         element: Element | HTMLDocument | Array<Element | HTMLDocument>,
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/screen.d.ts:11:59 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HTMLDocument'.

11         element: Element | HTMLDocument | Array<Element | HTMLDocument>,
                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/wait-for-dom-change.d.ts:4:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationObserverInit'.

4     mutationObserverOptions?: MutationObserverInit;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/wait-for-element-to-be-removed.d.ts:7:35 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationObserverInit'.

7         mutationObserverOptions?: MutationObserverInit;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/wait-for-element.d.ts:4:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationObserverInit'.

4     mutationObserverOptions?: MutationObserverInit;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/testing-library__dom/wait-for.d.ts:7:35 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MutationObserverInit'.

7         mutationObserverOptions?: MutationObserverInit;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 22 errors.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try to append `./tsconfig.json` with

```
"exclude" : {
  "packages/*/node_modules"
}
```

Or

```
"exclude" : {
  "**/node_modules"
}
```

?

--Edit

Looks like thing is not related to exclude at all.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588726/angular-typescript-exclude-is-not-working-in-tsconfig-json)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: No go on either :/

Comment: Updated answer. As for "paths" issue there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099016/how-to-set-paths-property-in-a-project-with-multiple-tsconfig-json)

Comment: odd that lib checking is enabled by default. I'm not interested in typechecking my imported dependencies, i want my team to evaluate our mutual codebase, not other peoples'.